# How to put a condition in a cycle for only one iteration?

Tags: python, for-loop

I try to read a set line by line and each line is one iteration. I try to create each iteration array using np. arange a np.reshape.

I want this remark to apply only to the first iteration

```
arr=np.arange(6)
arr=l.reshape(3,2)
```

This condition should apply to other iterations

```
l=np.arange(9)
arr=l.reshape(3,3)
```

Can you help me with this please?

input:demofile.txt

```
>=2 4 1 6 7
>=1 1 3 2
>=2 -2 -5 -8
```

full code:

```
#read data
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
#input preprocessing
p=1
for i in list(lines):
    if i[0] != '<' and i[0] != '>' and i[0] != '=':
        d = str(' '.join(i.split()))
        print(d)
            
    else:
        w = i.replace("=",'')
        w = w.replace(">",'')
        w = w.replace("<",'')
        w = ', '.join(w.split())
        c=np.array([w])            
        c1 = [int(i) for i in c[0].replace(" ", "").split(",")]
         #insert input to array
        c1=np.array(c1)
        # save first value in array
        frst=c1[0]
         #remove first value in array
        c1=np.delete(c1, 0)       
        n=len(c1)
        l=np.arange(6)
        arr=l.reshape(3,2)
        print(arr,'\n')
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question but why can't you use a loop index, starting at 0 and incrementing each iteration. When its value is 0 do one thing, otherwise do the other thing. Or a boolean `do_first` that's initially true and set to false first time through.

Comment: Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and apply the conditions based on the index.

Comment: is it possible other than enumerate? I need to edit the input first, so it's like a letter and I can't give an enumerate

Comment: `to apply only to the first iteration` - maybe I misunderstood; what are you referring to by iteration? I assumed it was the for loop. If it is not the for loop then it is not clear what you are asking or when you want to change from a (2,3) array to a (3,3) array.